# Typescript: error when checking if Map contains value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to check if a Map contains a value.
I tested this code in typescript playground.

```
let userMap = new Map();

userMap.set("user1", 'displayName');
userMap.set("user2", 'displayName2');

        console.log(friendsMapNew.has("user2")); //true
```

But when I use this code in a google cloud function I get this error:

```
error TypeError: userMap.has is not a function
```

This is the code I use in the cloud function.

```
let userMap = new Map();
userMap = getUserDocument.data()['userMap']; //if i console.log this, it shows a map like this:
{ K79DFS: 'Bob' }
if (userMap.has("Bob") === true) {console.log("user exists")}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getUserDocument.data()['userMap'];
```

This statement returns an `object` and not a `map`.

And object doesn't have `.has()` function. Hence the error.

You should use this instead if "Bob is a value" in your object

```
Object.values(userMap).includes("Bob") === true
```

To check for the property name you can use:

```
Object.keys(userMap).includes("K79DFS") === true
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a possibility to 'query' for the other value: here: K79DFS?